# VQE with error dim. mismatch using qiskit.aqua.vqe

Tags: quantum-algorithms, qiskit, qaoa, vqe

when i try to call the VQE from qiskit I get an error of dimmismatch. The input matrix is of a 16x16 shape and I could not find out what where I introduce the error. In the picture The input matrix and the qubit0p is shown. I get the same error when trying to use QAOA as well

Thank you for taking the time.

```
             self.C = self.C[:,:len(self.C[0])]
                    self.B = self.B[:,:len(self.B[0])]
                    print("Input:",self.C)
                    qubitOp = MatrixOperator(self.C)                    
                    print(qubitOp) 
                    backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
                    var_form = RYRZ(qubitOp.num_qubits,10)
                    optim = COBYLA()
                    vqe = VQE(qubitOp, var_form, optim)
                # Runs the VQE over the backend defined above.
                    result_vqe = vqe.run(backend)

                    print(qubitOp) # prints operator properties 
                    print('energy', result_vqe['energy'], '\n')
                    print(result_vqe)
```

Here is the error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-03f1f6dbe796> in <module>
     76 print_state(state)
     77 
---> 78 bundle_adjust(state)
     79 print("= Bundle Adjusted State =")
     80 print_state(state)

<ipython-input-1-03f1f6dbe796> in bundle_adjust(state)
     39 
     40     # note: intervene here with other optimizers
---> 41     o.optimize()
     42 
     43     # normalize scale (note: ~ is __invert__, *noisy is __imul__)

~\Bachelor-Project\BA\optimizerVQE3.py in optimize(self)
     65     # run optimization
     66     def optimize(self):
---> 67         for event in self.optimize_it():
     68             pass
     69 

~\Bachelor-Project\BA\optimizerVQE3.py in optimize_it(self)
    131 
    132                 # Runs the VQE over the backend defined above.
--> 133                     result_vqe = vqe.run(backend)
    134 
    135                     print(qubitOp) # prints operator properties

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\aqua\algorithms\quantum_algorithm.py in run(self, quantum_instance, **kwargs)
     65                 quantum_instance.set_config(**kwargs)
     66             self._quantum_instance = quantum_instance
---> 67         return self._run()
     68 
     69     @abstractmethod

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\aqua\algorithms\adaptive\vqe\vqe.py in _run(self)
    314         if self._auto_conversion:
    315             self._operator = \
--> 316                 self._config_the_best_mode(self._operator, self._quantum_instance.backend)
    317             for i in range(len(self._aux_operators)):
    318                 if not self._aux_operators[i].is_empty():

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\aqua\algorithms\adaptive\vqe\vqe.py in _config_the_best_mode(self, operator, backend)
    236                                 "achieve the better performance. We convert "
    237                                 "the operator to weighted paulis.")
--> 238                     ret_op = op_converter.to_weighted_pauli_operator(operator)
    239         return ret_op
    240 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\aqua\operators\op_converter.py in to_weighted_pauli_operator(operator)
     86                                list(itertools.product(possible_basis, repeat=num_qubits)),
     87                                task_kwargs={"matrix": operator._matrix},
---> 88                                num_processes=aqua_globals.num_processes)
     89         for trace_value, pauli in results:
     90             weight = trace_value * coeff

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\tools\parallel.py in parallel_map(task, values, task_args, task_kwargs, num_processes)
    142     results = []
    143     for _, value in enumerate(values):
--> 144         result = task(value, *task_args, **task_kwargs)
    145         results.append(result)
    146         _callback(0)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\aqua\operators\op_converter.py in _conversion(basis, matrix)
     36 def _conversion(basis, matrix):
     37     pauli = Pauli.from_label(''.join(basis))
---> 38     trace_value = np.sum(matrix.dot(pauli.to_spmatrix()).diagonal())
     39     return trace_value, pauli
     40 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in dot(self, other)
    361 
    362         """
--> 363         return self * other
    364 
    365     def power(self, n, dtype=None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    478         if issparse(other):
    479             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
--> 480                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
    481             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    482 

ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix you are printing seems to have 30 entries in each. When converting to Paulis form to run it expects the dimension to be a power of 2.

This code below (based on yours) does run when given a 16x16.

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import VQE
from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit.aqua.components.variational_forms import RYRZ
from qiskit.aqua.operators import MatrixOperator

np.random.seed = 75
matrix = np.random.rand(16, 16)
qubitOp = MatrixOperator(matrix)                    
print(qubitOp) 
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
var_form = RYRZ(qubitOp.num_qubits,10)
optim = COBYLA()
vqe = VQE(qubitOp, var_form, optim)
result_vqe = vqe.run(backend)

print(qubitOp) # prints operator properties 
print('energy', result_vqe['energy'], '\n')
print(result_vqe)
```